Django enable Multi-Tenant Social Login (tenants provide their own OAuth2 credentials)
I have a multi-tenant Django app created using the django-tenants package. My social login is handled by python-social-auth (more precisely drf_social_oauth2).
I'd like to allow tenants to provide their own Google OAuth2 credentials (client_id & client_secret) and authenticate using those. This way, the tenant has the ability to control who's allowed to use social login, e.g. restrict login to their "internal users".
Is there any way I can inject tenants' Google OAuth2 credentials in ConvertTokenView() based on what schema the request is made from?
Example pseudocode:
class ConvertTokenView(request):

  def post(self, request):
    tenant = get tenant based on schema
    backend.set_client_id(tenant.google_client_id)
    backend.set_client_secret(tenant.google_client_secret)
    backend.authenticate(request.body)
  
    return tokenResponse

Alternatively, I was thinking about dynamically modifying the following two settings.py settings:
# these are global, but i'd like each tenant to have their own creds
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = "<google_client_id>"
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = "<google_client_secret>"

This alternative method does not work, because these settings are only read on Django server startup.
EDIT: Added more context, added pseudocode

Can you describe the use-case better? Is your app going to be a middle-man between Google (or other OAuth instances) and other apps?

@Vegard thanks for pointing out my question wasn't specific enough. I've rephrased it a little bit and added more context. My Django backend should serve as an API that allows users to log into their tenants using Google social login. Instead of using global OAuth2 credentials, I'd like to allow tenants to provide their creds and therefore restrict the login to their "internal" users.

Would it be correct to say that you want to implement tenant-specific limitations on which OAuth "tenant" their users can authenticate against?

I believe that's one way of putting it. For example, when you setup Google OAuth screen it asks you about the user type. It can either be "External" or "Internal". If you select "Internal" and later create OAuth2 credentials, only internal users (users in your organization) will be able to authenticate using those credentials. Now each tenant in my Django project will have to provide these credentials and therefore restrict social login into their tenant to only users in their organization.

This should be doable, but I caution you to examine the security implications of this setup. Additionally, I haven't verified, but IIRC this kind of usage (from the user's perspective) is most likely against the TOS of major OAuth providers. The client secret should remain the client's secret, which it ceases to be after they've handed it to you. In my opinion, a better alternative (with almost as "strong" of a check) is to build out your tenant model, views, etc. with an allowed_domain attribute, and check the user's email against this attribute before doing any token exchange.
